# TypeError: Int Object is not callable Error

Tags: python, class, object, typeerror

## Why this error

##### Code

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def show(self):
        print(f"Value is {self._value}")
    
    @property
    def tenvalue(self):
        return self._value * 10
        
    @tenvalue.setter
    def tenvalue(self, nv: int):
        self.name = nv
        return nv * 10

obj = MyClass(10)
print(obj._value)
obj.tenvalues = 22
obj.tenvalue()
obj.show()
```

##### Output

```bash
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    obj.tenvalue()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I except it don't throw error. I create a class name ***`MyClass`*** and I create a setter so what I do please answer it

Comment: You made `tenvalue` a property and now you try to use it as a method (callable).

Comment: ```obj.tenvalues = 22``` already overwrote the ```obj.tenvalues()``` property setter.

Comment: @ewokx There is no `tenvalues` property or setter, that's just a typo in OP's code. It sets an unrelated field.

Comment: My bad.  I saw an extra s for some reasons.

Comment: Well, it's Python and snakes hisssssss... 

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#property), so you don't need to call it with parentheses.

In other words,

```
x = obj.tenvalue
print(x)
```

will print 100.

Now, if you tried

```
x()
```

you'd obviously get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` too.

As an aside,

- `obj.tenvalues = 22` does not do what you want because there's a typo there; it sets a vanilla field `tenvalues` to the value 22.
- Similarly, your setter for `tenvalue` is buggy; there is no `_name` field that would be used for anything. The setter should also not return anything.

All in all, you'd probably want something like

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def show(self):
        print(f"Value is {self._value}")

    @property
    def tenvalue(self):
        return self._value * 10

    @tenvalue.setter
    def tenvalue(self, nv: int):
        self._value = int(nv / 10)


obj = MyClass(10)
obj.show()
print(f"{obj.tenvalue=}")
obj.tenvalue = 220
obj.show()
```